# Why can we assume that $||w||^2 = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The context: We are looking at orthogonality and general Fourier series.
Given $\lambda$ an eigenvalue, and $w$ the corresponding eigenfunction, we are studying the eigenvalue problem: $w'' = -\lambda w$, subject to some Boundary Conditions.

My question is why can we assume in that:
$||w||^2 = 1$ $\iff$ $\int_{a}^{b} (w(x))^2 dx = 1 $? This was given in a proof, assumed without loss of generality

Comment: There’s an entire space of eigenfunctions, so once you have one in hand, you can always normalize it to get another with unit norm.

Comment: I would imagine it's because if $v=\frac{w}{\|w\|}$, then $v''=-\lambda v$ also and $\|v\|=1$

Comment: But why do we wish to normalize this $v$? What is the purpose? Is this to achieve orthogonality?

Comment: orthonormality maybe? Does the norm pop up in the proof at all?

Comment: The proof in question is that if we assume symmetric Boundary Conditions, and  if $f(x)f'(x) \leq 0$ evaluated at both endpoints, then there are no negative eigenvalues.

Comment: You can assume it because scaling the solution does not change the fact that it is still a solution of the same equation and endpoint conditions, provided you are using homogeneous endpoint conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you are looking at is linear; this means in particular that a multiple of a solution is again a solution. Depending on what you are doing having a norm-one solution could be useful (say you had computations where $\|w\|$ appears, having all those norms replaced by $1$ certainly simplify things).

Of course you cannot make that assumption completely for free: if for example you have a non-zero initial condition, multiplying a solution by a number does not give you another solution. But if your initial condition is zero, or if you are not considering initial conditions, you can always replace $w$ with $w/\|w\|$.